# JBoss EAP 6.3 standalone new missing/unsatisfied dependencies for security

Tags: xml, security, webserver, ssl-certificate, jboss6.x

I'm trying to setup JBoss EAP 6.3 standalone to use HTTPS protocol.  I think I have it set up correctly, but when I kick-off the 'standalone.sh' script in Linux, the log file shows this:

```
11:40:01,778 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.server.path."jboss.domain.config.dir" (missing) dependents: [
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.properties_authentication,
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ApplicationRealm.properties_authorization,
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.key-manager,
      service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.ManagementRealm.trust-manager,
      JBAS014799: ... and 3 more ]

11:40:01,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015964: Http management interface is not enabled
11:40:01,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
11:40:01,794 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19)
      started (with errors) in 4094ms - Started 236 of 290 services (17 services failed or
      missing dependencies, 66 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Not sure why startup is failing.  Perhaps someone can help me out?  Here are the relevant changes I made to 'host.xml':

```
        .
        .
        .
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl protocol="TLS">
                     <keystore path="/path/.keystore" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir" keystore-password="xxxxx" />
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <truststore path="/path/.keystore" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir" keystore-password="xxxx"/>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true" />
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        .
        .
        .
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket interface="management" secure-port="9443"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
    .
    .
    .
```

Here are the relevant changes I made to 'standalone.xml':

```
        .
        .
        .
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl protocol="TLS">
                     <keystore path="/path/.keystore" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir" keystore-password="xxxx" />
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <truststore path="/path/.keystore" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir" keystore-password="xxxx"/>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true" />
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        .
        .
        .
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443" />
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
            <ssl name="https" protocol="TLS" password="xxxx" certificate-key-file="/path/.keystore" certificate-file="/path/.keystore" />
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="myalias.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
    .
    .
    .
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the relative path. You run it in standalone mode so the `jboss.domain.config.dir` isn't defined. Use `jboss.server.config.dir` instead, which is the equivalent for this mode